# jquery asp.net cannot parse the json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am calling a webmethod from jquery and get the json object but I cannot parse and read the json object. please help me find what I am doing wrong. I have 3 alert() and I am putting comments next to them what they show...

my jquery code is this

```
$('#btn_second').click(function () {
            //$('#txt_isim_4').val('test arif');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Registration.aspx/get_selected_professional",
                data: "{'id':'2'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('1:' + data); // display [object Object]
                    alert('2:' + data.d.firstname); // display undefined
                    alert('3:' + data.d);  // display [{"id":"2","firstname":"arif"}]
                }
            });
        });
```

but I want to display only "Arif". is my json object wrong? should I use single quotation?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your `webmethod` is something like this:

```
public string get_selected_professional(string id)
{
   List<MyClass> requiredData= GetRequiredData(id);
   //your required logic

   //string requiredData= "[{\"id\":\"2\",\"firstname\":\"arif\"}]";
   //return requiredData;

   //or

   return new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(requiredData);
}
```

where `MyClass` is

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string firstname{get;set;}
}
```

then you should do this inside your ajax `:success` on the client side:

```
success: function (data) {
                    var jsonData =$.parseJSON(data);
                    alert('1:' + jsonData); // display [object Object]
                    alert('2:' + jsonData.d.firstname); // display undefined
                    alert('3:' + jsonData.d);             
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have array, use index and also use curly bracket in data to make object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ucCbY/2/)**

Change the json string to

```
[{"id":"2","firstname":"arif"}]
```

Use array index indexer to access its elements

```
data.d[0].id
```

Comment: what should I use instead?

Comment: try var jsonData= jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse you data:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
alert(result[0].Id);
```